# Replica in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can I store sum of two blocks as replica in HDFS ie if I have two blocks 1 and 2. Can the replica be 1,1,1+2 ? If possible,what are the changes to be made in source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop has RAID implementation in contrib/raid, so you can look at source code how it was implemented.
https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/src/contrib/raid